# Is it possible to provide auth token in DRF web api

Tags: django-rest-framework

I use token authorization in my sample api buit with django rest framework. Using web api interface I can navigate through my api. I can do any type of requests (post, put, patch, delete, option) to my api. But I don't see how to provide headers. Some of my endpoints require authorization, so even with GET request I can't access them from web api.

Is it possible to provide authentication token using django rest framework web api?

Answer (score 0):

Send your requests by Postman or other http clients rather than the web UI of rest framework.